# A new i/o library: a good idea or a really bad one?

Tags: java

For a long time I worked almost exclusively with input/output streams in java. However a few years ago I started exploring async I/O as well (e.g. running on jboss netty).

However when working in the async I/O world, I could not reuse any of my sync utilities. I also had to start on a rather large library of new I/O utilities and wasn't sure whether to aim for blocking or non-blocking.

As things go...I wrote an API on top of the existing I/O which supports both blocking and non-blocking and the utilities are written against that.

However because I/O is such a pervasive thing, I am unsure whether it is a wise thing to do. As an example take a Base64 encoder. Yes apache has a sync I/O version and yes java 8 finally has an async encoder. But I needed an encoder that could do both.

Same for quoted-printable, deflate,... and of course it should work for sockets (regular & ssl), files,... in single-threaded and multithreaded situations,... I needed utilities to chain together I/O sources, use delimiter-based or fixed-length I/O wrappers,... I needed protocol handlers for http, ftp,...

Many of these problems can be expressed in a blocking-neutral fashion or -given enough thought- could support both async and sync, allowing wide reusability.

In short: is it wise to introduce an abstraction on top of I/O, forcing basically every library that uses it (directly or indirectly) to use it as well?

**UPDATE**

At the core are the ReadableByteContainer and WritableByteContainer that -to the discerning eye- will look like a cross between stream I/O and channel I/O.

```
public interface ReadableByteContainer extends Closeable {
    public int read(byte [] bytes);
    public int read(byte [] bytes, int offset, int length);
}

public interface WritableByteContainer extends Closeable {
    public int write(byte [] bytes);
    public int write(byte [] bytes, int offset, int length);
    public void flush();
}
```

One of the utils built on it is the "Transcoder" api:

```
public interface ByteTranscoder {
    public void transcode(ReadableByteContainer in, WritableByteContainer out);
    public void flush(WritableByteContainer out);
}
```

which allows you to do something like:

```
ByteContainer container = IOUtils.newByteContainer();
container = IOUtils.wrap(
    container,
    TranscoderUtils.wrapOutput(container, new Base64Encoder())
);
container.write("test".getBytes());
System.out.println(new String(IOUtils.toBytes(container)));
```

This code will output the base64 encoded bytes of "test".

The thing is, the Base64Encoder is capable of encoding the data in an asynchronous manner, it won't block if the output container reports that no data was written nor will it block if the input container reports that no data is available. You can continue the transcoding by calling "transcode()" again.

This works both in a jboss netty context where you get the content piece by asynchronous piece and in the streaming world where everything blocks until it can read/write.

Comment: Can you post a short example of the sync and async sides of your wrapper?   I may just be confused, but it seems you may be conflating some concepts.

Comment: Streams are an abstraction over I/O, so the wisdom of introducing an abstraction seems self-evident, assuming the abstraction has a useful purpose.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt Updated the original question

Comment: What existing libraries have you looked at?  What about the asynchronous IO feature in Java 7?  If you just think you can build a better library, go for it, but that's almost certainly not the fastest path to a working application.

Comment: Have you used java.nio?  Channels etc have been around for a long time.  Since version 1.4 I believe.  (Not sure whether automatic compression/base64 encode/decode were in there, but shouldn't have been difficult to fit into that particular abstraction)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps an interesting follow-up to this is the actual library that has recently been added to github: https://github.com/nablex/utils-io

Note that the library has gone through an extensive rewrite since this question was asked.

Other libraries based on this one:

- https://github.com/nablex/utils-codec : adds encoding/decoding for base64, deflate, gzip & quoted printable
- https://github.com/nablex/utils-mime : uses the other libraries to perform low-level mime & s/mime parsing and formatting. As a proof of concept I also wrote a lightweight HTTP client on top of it that might make it to github at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're abstracting the wrong thing. Your library does not need to actually handle the I/O. You already have libraries in hand that do synchronous or asynchronous I/O. Rewriting those libraries and merging them together is *not* abstraction. In fact, it might be a violation of the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Why not simply write a library that provides a uniform interface to those libraries you mentioned? Underneath the covers, it is simply calling one library or the other. That's *true* abstraction.

Just my two cents.

Comment: The library is what you describe: a uniform interface over both I/O libraries. It does reimplement some things (e.g. buffering) because the existing tools are obviously not cross-library. It does **not** reinvent file I/O, network I/O etc, it uses the available libraries for that.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I guess I misunderstood. No, that's not a bad way to do things, at least in my uninformed opinion.